# How can I add a script reference to _Layout.cshtml with a NuGet package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have a helper called 'SelectionOtherInput', for capturing a meaningful value when a user chooses 'Other' on a select list.

I have built a NuGet package for it, and it is ready to use as installed, provided there is a reference to it's JavaScript file in the page using it, or easier, in the `_Layout.cshtm file`. It's easy to tell the user, "install the NuGet package, then add this script reference", but why not tell them, "copy these files, then add this script reference?" and skip NuGet?

I realised editing the file may be complicated and involved the CodeDOM< but them's the risks.

***Bounty guaranteed as soon as permitted!***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328980/create-a-custom-powershell-script-for-nuget-that-adds-a-custom-target-to-the-csp

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Unix _Layout.cshtm file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="menu">
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Movies", "Index", "Movies")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
</ul> 
<section id="main">
@RenderBody()
 <p>Copyright W3schools 2012. All Rights Reserved.</p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```