# NuGet Uninstall script – Remove Import from Project

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget, uninstallation, nuget-package

I’m working on a NuGet package which adds a MSBuild target to a project using the install script.

I found an example of how to add the target to the project here: [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jstangroome/NuGetReferenceHintPathRewrite/master/tools/install.ps1)

Now I want to create an uninstall script which removes the import when the user uninstalls the package. …Sadly I can’t find any example of this.

How can I remove an import form a Visual Studio project with the NuGet uninstall.ps1 script?

Comment: I would try to include the MSBuild target with the NuGet package itself. Then you do not need to use a PowerShell script at all - http://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a custom powershell script for nuget that adds a custom target to the csproj BeforeBuild step](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328980/create-a-custom-powershell-script-for-nuget-that-adds-a-custom-target-to-the-csp)